# how set a condition on 'from' lookup in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need execute this code,

```js
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: {if:{"$entity": "commodity"},then:"commodities",else:"posts"},
          localField: "entityId",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "orders_info",
        },
      }])
```

but get this error

> Mongo Server error (MongoCommandException): Command failed with error
> 9 (FailedToParse): ''from' option to $lookup must be a string, but was
> type object' on server localhost:27017.

The full response is:

```
{ 
    "ok" : 0.0, 
    "errmsg" : "'from' option to $lookup must be a string, but was type object", 
    "code" : 9.0, 
    "codeName" : "FailedToParse"
}
```

Comment: The `$lookup` has various formats - you need to use the one which has the `pipeline` parameter / option. It will allow you to specify a condition.

Comment: You cant do this, because `from` doesn't accept an expression it always gets the name of a collection, also i don't think there is a way to do this in general, because we don't have a way to have optional stages. [See the docs also](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Comment: in one column exist two type id,how lookup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Takis_ mentioned, we probably do not have a general way to achieve the expected behaviour. However, we can have a workaround to conditionally lookup both collections and `$setUnion` the result together.

```js
db.temporari.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "commodities",
      "let": {
        eid: "$entityId",
        e: "$entity"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$eid",
                    "$_id"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$e",
                    "commodities"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "commoditiesLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "posts",
      "let": {
        eid: "$entityId",
        e: "$entity"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$eid",
                    "$_id"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$e",
                    "posts"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "postsLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "orders_info": {
        "$setUnion": [
          "$commoditiesLookup",
          "$postsLookup"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rPx1bIH97oi) for your reference.